# Comparing the time requirements of addition and division operation in GPU (CUDA)

Tags: time, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I need to find out that how much division operation is faster than addition operation in a GPU. I wrote a code that adds two random vectors of length 1000000 and measured the running time of kernel function. Here is my code

```
         __global__ void addition(float *a, float *b, float *c, int n)
            {

                int id = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;


                if (id < n)
                    c[id] = a[id] + b[id];
            }
        int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
        {
           srand(time(NULL));

            int n = 1000000;
            clock_t t1,t2;

            float *h_a;
            float *h_b;
            float *h_c;
            float *d_a;
            float *d_b;
            float *d_c;

            size_t bytes = n*sizeof(float);


            h_a = (float*)malloc(bytes);
            h_b = (float*)malloc(bytes);
            h_c = (float*)malloc(bytes);

            cudaMalloc(&d_a, bytes);
            cudaMalloc(&d_b, bytes);
            cudaMalloc(&d_c, bytes);

            int i;

            for( i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
                h_a[i] =(float)rand();
                h_b[i] =(float)rand();
            }


            cudaMemcpy( d_a, h_a, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
            cudaMemcpy( d_b, h_b, bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

         int blockSize, gridSize;

              blockSize =1;
              gridSize =1;

                t1 = clock();
                addition<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(d_a, d_b, d_d, n);
                t2 = clock();

            cudaMemcpy( h_c, d_c, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

        float time = t2-t1;

            printf("Time is: %f\n", time);

            cudaFree(d_a);
            cudaFree(d_b);
            cudaFree(d_c);

            free(h_a);
            free(h_b);
            free(h_c);

     return 0;
    }
```

In this code I just considered 1 thread per block. I wrote the same code for division by just replacing "+" with "/" in kernel function.

The elapsed time for both codes where almost the same, which means division needs same time as addition. Could it be really possible? As far as I know the division is more complex and slower than other operations like addition, so is my code incorrect then?

Comment: Your kernel is memory bound, rather than compute bound, so not difference in execution time between element-wise addition and element-wise division of two vectors is expected.

Comment: @njuffa Thank you for your comment. How should I change that to compute bound?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to measure the speed of a particular operation by timing the whole kernel running time, you need to make that operation a major proportion of the kernel running.

In your above kernel code, there are two issues.

1. Each thread will only do the operation you want to measure once, but at the same time it will access the global memory 3 times, which takes the major part of the kernel running time, as well as other overhead (calculating `id` and comparing `id < n`);
2. Without a `cudaDeviceSynchronize();` after launching the kernel, you are measuring the kernel launching time instead of kernel running time.

To solve issue 1, you could use unrolled for loop to repeat the target operation and minimize the global memory access. For example in the following kernel, a block with 1024 threads will do 'div' 1,024,000 x `n` times and global memory access only once.

```
__global__ void div(float* result, float a, float b, int n) {
  float r = 1;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
#pragma unroll
    for (int j = 0; j < 500; j++) {
      r /= a;
      r /= b;
    }
  }
  if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
    result[blockIdx.x] = r;
  }
}
```

For issue 2, don't forget to add `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` after kernel launching on the host side.

```
int grid = 1000;
int block = 1024;
int num_repeat = 100;
double t1;

thrust::device_vector<float> result(grid, 0.0);
float* raw_result = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(result.data());

t1 = omp_get_wtime();
div<<<grid, block>>>(raw_result, 1.25, 0.8, num_repeat);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
t1 = omp_get_wtime() - t1;
```

With the above code, you could use either a large grid dim and block dim to fully utilize the GPU, or only 1 thread/block and 1 block/grid, to measure the speed. They will give similar results.

On a K40c, add is ~21x faster than div.

```
add: time: 0.072437s  speed: 1413.64Gflops  result[0]: 100001
div: time: 1.52071s  speed: 67.337Gflops  result[0]: 1
speed ratio (add/div): 20.9935
```

---

Actually an even simpler method is to use device timing function [`clock64()`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#time-function) with the launch setting `<<<1, 1>>>`. It gives a speed ratio of ~19x.

```
__global__ void test(float* result, float a, float b) {
  float r_add = 0, r_div = 1;

  long long t1 = clock64();
#pragma unroll
  for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    r_add += a;
    r_add += b;
  }
  long long t2 = clock64();
#pragma unroll
  for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    r_div /= a;
    r_div /= b;
  }
  long long t3 = clock64();
  long long t4 = clock64();

  result[0] = (t2 - t1) - (t4 - t3);
  result[1] = (t3 - t2) - (t4 - t3);
  result[2] = float(t3 - t2 - (t4 - t3)) / float(t2 - t1 - (t4 - t3));
  result[3] = t4 - t3;
  result[4] = r_add;
  result[5] = r_div;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it makes lots of sense. So in your approach you just add or divide two specific numbers instead of two arrays in order to reduce access to global memory, right?